# Acumatica REST API - set checkbox in a mapped field when creating a sales order

Tags: rest, acumatica, acumatica-kb

We have a field in our Sales Order page that contains a list of checkboxes.

[image: Checkboxes in field]

I've cloned the Default Endpoint, and added this field to my copy of the Sales Order Webservice endpoint.  I am able to read this field when I query a sales order (get), but I am struggling to figure out how to check a checkbox in this field using the API with a put when I am creating a sales order.  I tried to check the "Team Store" checkbox with this value:

OrderNature: {'value': {'Team Store': {'value': {'Selected': {'value': 'True'}}}}}

but it is ignored.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered my problem.   I was not calling the new endpoint I had created, I was still calling "Default".  Also to set the field I needed only to send the text of the checkbox, OrderNature : {'value':'Team Store'}

Comment: If this resolves your issue can you mark the question as answered?